# (GNU) find -mtime using variables

Tags: linux, variables, unix, find, gnu

I'm trying to find files using `-mtime +(variable)`, but everytime I execute below in GNU I'm getting an error:

> find: missing argument to `-mtime'

Tried in AIX and it worked.

```
#------config-------#
cat hkeep.cfg
#<Directory to be purge>,<Days to Purge>
/home/fbmadm/logs,15

#------MAIN-------#
for line in `cat hkeep.cfg | grep -v "#"`;do
hkDir=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
hkCnt=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}'` 

find $hkDir -mtime +$hkCnt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `echo line` may help you figure out the problem:

```
for line in `cat hkeep.cfg | grep -v "#"`;do
hkDir=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $1}'`
hkCnt=`echo $line | awk -F"," '{print $2}'` 
echo find $hkDir -mtime +$hkCnt
find $hkDir -mtime +$hkCnt
```

Comment: The error you mentioned may imply that your variable `$hkCnt` is empty.